# Uploadify File Rename

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using the Uploadify jQuery plugin for PHP to upload a file.  One thing I am stuck on is that I need to be able to rename the file being uploaded so that I can post that information to my script that inserts data into the mysql database.  Can anyone please advise on how to do this?

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :-

```
$targetFolder =  FCPATH.'/resources/images/users/temp/'; // Relative to the root
    if (!empty($image)) 
    {
        $time=strtotime("now");
        $image['Filedata']['name']=$time.'.jpg';
        $tempFile = $image['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $targetFolder.$image['Filedata']['name'];

        // Validate the file type
        $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
        $fileParts = pathinfo($image['Filedata']['name']);

        if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) 
        {
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetPath);
            echo '1';
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'Invalid file type.';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly rename the filename as you want in your uploadify.php

Then you just need to return $targetPath from your uploadify.php file, like this --

`echo $targetPath`

no need to use echo '1'

And now you have to get the renamed file name. You can get this in onUploadSuccess function.
onUploadSuccess() takes three parameters (file, data, response),

where file gives you the actual name of file you browsed through your computer, and data gives you the renamed file name which you generated through your uploadify.php code as per your requirement.

So you can try the below code --

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        alert('Renamed file name is - ' + data);
    }
```

I hope this will help out. One of my friend told me this, and I got my work done then :)

Comment: It works... but I can't see why. I remember that you needed to answer with a literal `1` to inform the frontend of a successfull upload. I guess everybody does that with headers now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use uploadify.php just go right before the function move_uploaded_files and change the target name.

Anyways you do it this should work. Post the code you have if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: What you're saying is exactly what I was thinking, however, the code that inserts data such as the title of the post and description are run through another .php file which does the actual query to the database.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What? Thats not what you asked at all! Post the actual code you have. For sure when move_uploaded_files happens the filename is there and you should be able to track down when its passed to the other script and then rename it.

Answer (score 0):

```
This will put file in new folder with same file name as source file

$source   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$newPath = $folder.'/'.$filename;
rename($source, $newPath);

/*----------------------*/

to have a new filename
    function getExtension($path)
    {
        $result = substr(strtolower(strrchr($path, '.')), 1);
        $result = preg_replace('/^([a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z].*/', '$1', $result);
        if ($result === 'jpeg' || empty($result) === true) {
            $result = 'jpg';
        }
        return $result;
    }

$source   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$newfileName=$folder."/"."abc".getExtension($filename);
rename($source, $newfileName);
```